# Can you mix TestNG and JUnit Assertions together within the same Test / Framework?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, testng

Can you mix TestNG and JUnit Assertions together within the same Test / Framework?

For example lets say I have developed a framework, is it possible to have the following:

- A TestNG class which uses JUNit Assertions
- A TestNG which uses both Junit and TestNG assertions?

Thanks For your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is no. If you notice when you mark a method as a test with the @Test annotation you are prompted which framework to import. Same thing witht the assertions as well. Think about it, a Testng test wouldn't be able to 'record' a result if prompted to use a Junit assertion. Hence, when writing a test with a Testng @Test annotation; the Assertion automatically defaults to a Testng assertion. [image]

*Update, after OP's comments:*

**Gbru check your \projectFolder\test-output\junitreports**
the xml you are looking for might already be there..

Taken from:
[testNG doc Junit reports](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-junitreports)

6.2.3 - JUnitReports

TestNG contains a listener that takes the TestNG results and outputs an XML file that can then be fed to JUnitReport. Here is an example, and the ant task to create this report:

```
<target name="reports">
  <junitreport todir="test-report">
    <fileset dir="test-output">
      <include name="*/*.xml"/>
    </fileset>

    <report format="noframes"  todir="test-report"/>
  </junitreport>
</target>
```

Comment: Not a problem at all, thanks for voting my answer promptly. By the way Gbru, what are you trying to achieve, you have an existing JUnit framework and trying to migrate to TestNG or something? Just curious, maybe there is a way around it :)

Comment: i have developed a TestNG frameowork, which is running in MS TFS, what i have found there is only a JUNIT option in the TFS to read xml files, it seems to read most of the data fine but when it reaches the TestNG assertion failures it cannot read the reports :/

Comment: I see, are these the test results by any chance? Because if they are, you are in luck, Testng produces automatically a xml file after each run.

Comment: yeah @ Xwris Stoixeia these are the test results, currently im reading the surefire JUnit.xmls but i think where the TestNG requires JUnit and the xml contains TestNG sytnax its throwing errors :/

Comment: I agree with the answer; but I find the explanation is simply wrong: what your IDE suggests to you is just a suggestion. Assuming that your class path setup is correct, there should be no direct obstacles from **importing** different annotations and applying them.

Comment: Aha! Goto your project folder and find the automatically created folder called test-output. Inside there, there is another folder called junitreports, does that help?

Comment: @Gbru check the updated answer, I think there is a way to produce JUnit reports!

Comment: @Xwris Stoixeia thanks, im wondering if i need to add the code in the TestNG xml or create an Ant build file

Comment: @Xwris Stoixeia I have the following folder etc: \projectFolder\test-output\junitreports, i think the problem is the JUnit reports still contain TestNG assertions which the TFS cannot read

Comment: Got you :) I don't think you need to add the TestNG xml I think you need to point JunitReport to collect the xml files from the junitreports folder. Try using ant as it mentioned in the official spec. Best of luck! http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html

Comment: @Xwris Stoixeia think i may have found the issue, a certain character cannot be read by the TFS, thanks again for your help

Comment: No problem m8, glad that I was of some help! Take care :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use any assertion library you want in your tests: TestNG, JUnit, AssertJ, Hamcrest, ...

It is possible to run JUnit tests with TestNG too because TestNG supports JUnit if you configure it well.

Comment: This is the only correct answer.  The question was about assertions.  The other answers are about annotations and test runners.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind what the **essence** of both frameworks is: they **execute** testcases.

Of course you can put whatever annotations you want into your code. But the point is: those annotations by themselves mean **nothing**. They are just **markers** on classes/method definitions.

It is the underlying **framework**, that checks for their presence at runtime  and does "something" when this or that annotation is found.

Meaning: in order for JUnit resp. TestNG annotations to cause the desired effects at runtime ... you have to run the test either within the JUnit or  the TestNG framework. But - you can't run both frameworks in parallel, in the same JVM, on the same source code.

In other words: if there is a need to do so, then you have to **separate** your testcases into different buckets: one for JUnit tests; one for TestNG tests. But forget about **mixing** things on a lower level!

And even when it would be technically possible to run both frameworks "together" in one JVM - you still do **not** want to do that. Simply because those frameworks are not designed to support this requirement; and because nobody else does it; and therefore your chances of hitting all kinds of obvious and subtle bugs is way too high!

But I have to admit: I misread the question. If its *solely* about dealing with those asserts, then I agree to Grasshoper's comment to this answer; I do not see a hard technical reason for that to *not* work.

Comment: Better explanation... Correct me if I am wrong, both junit and testng assertions throw java.lang.AssertionError when an assertion fails. So it should be independent of which assertion one uses, no matter which framework you are using to run the test.

Comment: Maybe in the simple case. But what about other annotations such as @Before? When those are not treated correctly, what does it help that a corresponding fail is accounted for correctly? Sometimes freedom of choice is valuable, but I think a development team should be able to agree on ONE test framework. And as said, if you really need both, then organize things into two separate buckets.

Comment: Before,After and other configuration methods are part of the test framework which should be fixed for a project. My query was regarding just the assertion statements part. Similar to how hamcrest  matchers integrates easily with both testng and junit frameworks. So should'nt I get the same behaviour with testng assertions in junit run tests or vice versa.

Comment: You are probably correct. I didn't get the "core" of your question. Updated my answer; and you got my vote for this interesting idea!

Comment: Well I am not the OP just commented on your answer and I think the accepted answer is not correct.

Comment: @GhostCat maybe edit your answer to remove the irrelevant parts?  Your edit right at the end is pretty buried, so the answer still is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is `NO`. Either you can use TestNG or JUnit at a time. You can't integrate both at a time.